# Is this C++ FFT function equivalent to "fft" matlab function?

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, transform, fft

I have always used the function "fft(x)" in matlab where "x" is a vector of complex numbers. I am looking for an easy to use function in C++ that would return complex numbers.

I have found this code : http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/dft/

If it is equivalent, how can I use it ? Thank you for your time !

```
  /*
   This computes an in-place complex-to-complex FFT 
   x and y are the real and imaginary arrays of 2^m points.
   dir =  1 gives forward transform
   dir = -1 gives reverse transform 
*/
short FFT(short int dir,long m,double *x,double *y)
{
   long n,i,i1,j,k,i2,l,l1,l2;
   double c1,c2,tx,ty,t1,t2,u1,u2,z;

   /* Calculate the number of points */
   n = 1;
   for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
      n *= 2;

   /* Do the bit reversal */
   i2 = n >> 1;
   j = 0;
   for (i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
      if (i < j) {
         tx = x[i];
         ty = y[i];
         x[i] = x[j];
         y[i] = y[j];
         x[j] = tx;
         y[j] = ty;
      }
      k = i2;
      while (k <= j) {
         j -= k;
         k >>= 1;
      }
      j += k;
   }

   /* Compute the FFT */
   c1 = -1.0; 
   c2 = 0.0;
   l2 = 1;
   for (l=0;l<m;l++) {
      l1 = l2;
      l2 <<= 1;
      u1 = 1.0; 
      u2 = 0.0;
      for (j=0;j<l1;j++) {
         for (i=j;i<n;i+=l2) {
            i1 = i + l1;
            t1 = u1 * x[i1] - u2 * y[i1];
            t2 = u1 * y[i1] + u2 * x[i1];
            x[i1] = x[i] - t1; 
            y[i1] = y[i] - t2;
            x[i] += t1;
            y[i] += t2;
         }
         z =  u1 * c1 - u2 * c2;
         u2 = u1 * c2 + u2 * c1;
         u1 = z;
      }
      c2 = sqrt((1.0 - c1) / 2.0);
      if (dir == 1) 
         c2 = -c2;
      c1 = sqrt((1.0 + c1) / 2.0);
   }

   /* Scaling for forward transform */
   if (dir == 1) {
      for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
         x[i] /= n;
         y[i] /= n;
      }
   }

   return(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Two possible approaches: try to understand the code and see if it does similar calculation steps. Second approach: try  numerical equivalent testing. I.e. feed in test data and compare the outputs.

Comment: If you know how to call C++ functions, then you already know how to use it. The comments at the top tell you what inputs are expected.  Also, as for your question of "equivalent", they would be numerically equivalent but the process of computing the FFT is not the same. `fft` uses FFTW, which uses the radix decomposition to achieve faster runtimes.

Comment: A standard would be the [fftw library](http://www.fftw.org). In your searches, it helps to favor tested, documented and widely used libraries.

Comment: You'd have more luck here with C++ experts if you start by explaining what FFT is supposed to do in Matlab. Not everybody here knows that.

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to tell you "how" to use it since we don't know in what form are your inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will follow your advice by making some test on real data. I am a beginner in C++ , I coded several small project but I sometimes get stuck. Here, for instance, I would expect a type Complex as output. Ok for the input, I guess I will be able to take real and imag part of my complex numbers. My input is a vector of complexe numbers.

Comment: @LaGabriella If you want to use this code untouched, you can perhaps access your vector and declare new `double` arrays that split up the real and imaginary components and use this function. If you really want to get it working with your code, modify the above function so that it works with an input vector of complex numbers instead.  That way you simply have to provide the vector and let the algorithm do the rest. You may also want to return a vector that contains the transformed result or mutate the input to reflect this information (that's what the code currently does).

Comment: @rayryeng ,thank you for your answer. Actually, what i didn t understand is the output type. Why "short "?  In the description, it is written "complex to complex" .. Also, is this code seems helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121574/safe-and-fast-fft  ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Suggestion:

I had same problem. I used fft library from fftw.
http://www.fftw.org/download.html
Its performance is similar to matlab.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this but which one should I use ? I admit I was a bit lost when i saw all these files.

Comment: libfftw3-3, libfftw3f-3, libfftw3l-3 these library files (.lib) extension.

Comment: You also need fftw3.h header file. 3 export definition files (.def), 3 exports libary files (.exp); Those file has same name as .lib files.

Comment: Copy these 10 files in your project directory and include fftw3.h in your project.

Comment: Thank you K.M Shihab Uddin . I will give it a try. May i ask you if i Only have to put these files in the project directory without any other configuration in visual studio ?

Comment: You have to copy the .lib file names in linker>>input>>additional dependencies

Comment: just like including any library

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine at first glance. The original FFT is not a lot of code.

One feature of the FFT is that it is an **inplace** operation. Many higher level bindings effectively hide that fact.

So you put your real and imaginary parts into the x and y arrays. After the executing the function you read those same arrays for your result.

This particularly simple implementation will only work with powers of 2 as the original FFT. If you have inputs of lengths other than powers of 2 you could zero-pad your signal.

Google the book `Numerical Recipes`  and `fft` (older versions are freely available) if you want to read up on the background of the FFT. The version in that book is different from other implementations in that you have to feed in the real and imaginary parts interleaved.

What I'm missing on the implementation that you are quoting is the use of pi or trigonometric functions. You'll have to try it out to compare against Matlab.